# Find the angle between two coordinate systems.

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

[image]
Hi, I need to find out the angle between the two vectors $x$ and $x'$ based on the two angles $\alpha$ and $\alpha'$, also the points $A$ and $O'$ are known in both coordinate systems $(O,x,y)$ and $(O',x',y')$. Basically I need to find out the angle between the two coordinate systems.
Note that $OA$ and $x'$ are not parallel. Thank you in advance for your answers and don't hesitate to ask for further details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From

$$OA=OO'+O'A\implies O'A=OA-OO'$$

we can find O'A in the system (O,x,y) and then find its angle with x axis.

We can also can find the angle of O'A in the system (O',x',y').

Thus by the difference we can find the angle between x and x'.

Comment: I have a small edit in this problem, let,s say we do not have the coordinates of $O'$ in $(O,x,y)$, can we find its coordinates based on what we have? and then find the angle between x and x' as you mentioned.

Comment: No in case this case you can’t find an unique solution: imagine that the system (O’,x’,y’) rotates around A.

Comment: That's true, So I think we need another point in $(O',x',y')$.

Comment: In general to define the position of (O’,x’,y’) we need three points (eg O’ and acis versors) and two points if we know orientation of one axis with respect to the other (eg y’ 90 degree counterclockwise with respect o x’)